# How to format section of website when screen is SM with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Good Morning,

I have a question about how to format part of a website when its at a different browser size.

For example: This is what my top nav looks like at the LG size.

[Nav LG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK7Zq.png)

But When I get to the SM size, it shows unformatted which looks bad like so:

[Nav SM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8c5A.png)

My question is, how do I target that specifically at the SM size and format it when its only at the size?

Would I use a media query or another class in Boostrap? Im not sure where to go from here, any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Start here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-wrapping

Comment: Please include code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use media queries to specify specific px/% sizes I believe. But bootstrap has built in rows with columns that have built in break points and sizes. col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 etc.

Heres the bootstrap link to it:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: you want the grid options in the guide to the right. I recommend watching a youtube vid or something! GL

Comment: Ahhh ok thank you Crayton! There is a section on media queries in your link so I will look around there. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: @Ally12 Awesome! I would lean you towards the side of looking into columns and rows since bootstrap offers it and I believe it will do what you need it to do. media queries can get a bit complex.

Comment: I understand how to use the columns and rows in bootstrap I just dont know how to apply the specific styling to each screen size like SM, LG, and such